# Make 2nd div (and all divs to follow) appear under an absolute div

Tags: css

I currently have:

```
<div className='header'></div>
<div className='hero-img'></div>
<div className='paragraph'></div>
<div className='cta'></div>
```

I want to overlay header onto hero image. Here is my CSS:

```
.hero-image {
height: 60vh;
min-height: 10em;
width: 100vw;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
margin-left: -50vw;
margin-right: -50vw;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
```

So now the header is properly overlayed over the hero image, but now the paragraph has moved up and is also over the hero image. How do I move paragraph (and all subsequent divs) down, now that I've done position:absolute on the hero image and anchored it to the top?

Comment: incomplete css.. you can post snippet in question.

Answer (score 0):

Use position: absolute; on .header not in .hero-img and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `image` position `absolute` make `header`'s position `absolute`.
Learn [positions](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) before applying else you will do random things and get random results.

```css
.image{
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:red;
}
h2{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Good
  </h2>
  <div class='image'></div>
</div>
<p>Para1 Para1 Para1 Para1 Para1 Para1 Para1 Para1</p>
```

Here only `header` will be removed from normal layouting and will be position on parent divs top left. Everything else will remain as usual flow.

In absolute position just imagine content if `header` is absent and then position `header` at top-left of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 document section elements to your advantage here.

(And you really *should* be using `<header>` instead of `<div class="header">`...)

```
<header>
</header>

<main>
<div className='paragraph'></div>
<div className='cta'></div>
</main>
```

not forgetting to give `<header>` a background image:

```
header {
background-image: url(/hero-img.jpg);
}
```

If the `<header>` is `140px` tall, you can give it absolute positioning:

```
header {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

and you can give `<main>` a `margin-top`:

```
main {
margin-top: 160px;
}
```